# Issue resolving conflits with git in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

I'm using bitbucket in netbeans and i'm having a problem when using the pull function. 
In my local changes I added some lines in the middle of the code, I've already commited it, but when I pull the existing file from the remote branch, and I try to resolve conflits, all code is considered different between the files instead of only my added lines. 
What could be wrong?

This was de result of 'git status' and then 'git pull':

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

mergulhao@MERGULHAO-PC /C/Users/mergulhao/snimar/snimar/autoMetadata/src (master
)
$ git pull
Password for 'https://iFalcao@bitbucket.org':
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/snimar/snimar
   2abf060..6c4be77  master     -> origin/master
Auto-merging autoMetadata/src/MD_Classes.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in autoMetadata/src/MD_Classes.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Note in the image below that when I try to resolve conflicts, all code is marked in red instead of only my new line

```
del contact_temp
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the output of `git status` please?

Comment: Please take a look to my edited question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that there haven't been any changes to invisible characters made either on the remote or by yourself? For example you would see something like this if the line endings had been changed between Windows style and UNIX style, or if tabs had been swapped with spaces.